# C#/.NET Not generic LinkedList is it present?

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

I wanna find something like linked list but non from generic namespace, is it possible ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the specific performance/behaviour profile of linked-lists re inserts? Or are you just after "a list of arbitrary items"

Comment: At least, I need native order of inserted .

Comment: *Nobody* targets .NET 1.x anymore.  This is a complete waste of your time.  Well, ours.

Comment: @jitm - "native order of inserted" - I don't quite follow you there. What exactly are you after there?

Comment: @Hans - not *quite* true; but certainly increasingly hard to support.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I mean insertion-order.

Comment: @jitm - `ArrayList` will preserve insertion order... in fact, only a few specific lists (the sorted lists / dictionary implementions) will break insertion order.

Comment: @Marc, Yes I know, but I need all specific LinkedList implementation, insertion order it was first that I remember and have written ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using .NET 1.x, you would need to either implement this from scratch (which isn't that hard really), or settle for `ArrayList`. I know the position - for a utility library I ended up writing the list primitives from scratch, because:

- 1.x lacks the generic versions
- Silverlight lacks the non-generic versions

so to work on all platforms, I rolled my own (I had other unique features too, which made hacking around with something like a `using` alias undesirable - such as thread-safe tail-iteration while appending items).

Comment: may be present some opensource implementation for .net 1.x ?

Comment: @jitm - of a linked list? Most text-book examples would suffice (translated to C#, obviously). My *specific* ones weren't linked list, else you would be more than welcome to them.